# Iterating with zip function in python, over several columns, gives error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame like this:

```
    dx1      dx2    dx3    dx4    dx5       dx6     dx7
0   25041   40391   5856    0     V4511    V5867    30000
1   25041   40391   25081   5856  5363     3572     0
2   25041   40391   42822   0     5856     0        0
3   25061   40391   0       0     0        0        0
4   25041   40391   0       5856  25081    V4511    25051
```

I want to create additional column(s) for cell values like, 5856. So there will be a column 5856 with value as 1 or 0 if 5856 occurs in that particular row in any dxs columns. I am using this code. It does not give any error, but warning, and does not fill new column in right way.

```
X11['5856'] = np.NAN
i = 0

for value in zip(X11.loc[:,'dx1':'dx59']):
    if value == 5856:
        X11['5856'][i] = 1
    else:
        X11['5856'][i] = 0
    i+1
```

The warling I am getting is this:

```
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\__main__.py:8: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
```

And I am getting 5856 column with values: 0, NaN, NaN.....

This is expected result: In fact I want to create multiple columns for different cell values like 25041, 5363 etc.

```
    dx1      dx2    dx3    dx4    dx5       dx6     dx7    5856
0   25041   40391   5856    0     V4511    V5867    30000   1
1   25041   40391   25081   5856  5363     3572     0       1
2   25041   40391   42822   0     5856     0        0       1
3   25061   40391   0       0     0        0        0       0
4   25041   40391   0       5856  25081    V4511    25051   1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find a particular value in a dataframe, I would use the `.isin` method as follows:

```
# Add a column
df['5856'] = df.isin([5856]).any(1)
```

This returns a boolean series checking whether the desired value is in each row. Then you can simply replace the relative `True` or `False` values with 1 and 0.

Comment: Thank you. Just adding another function gave me int values:                        df['5856'] = df.isin([5856]).any(1).astype(int)